# HttpOnly Cookies not set to browser (client side with laravel)

Tags: node.js, laravel, cookies, setcookie, cookie-httponly

NEED YOUR EXPERIENCE AND KNOWLEDGE.

im building a web application where client-side using Laravel 8 (fckid.test using valet or http://localhost:8000) and Node.js (http://localhost:3000) for server-side API.
Serverside using **JWT** for authorization and sending the token through **Httponly Cookie**.

My problem is when testing it with Postman and ThunderClient, it works perfectly as shown by picture below
[image]

here is on postman
[image]

here is how my backend looks like

1.Router

```
const usersController = require('../controllers/users.controller')
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

router.post('/login', usersController.login)
```

2. The Controller

```
    exports.login = (req, res, next) => {

        const data = {
            email: req.body.email,
            password: req.body.password
        }
        console.log('Request made by :', req.headers)
    
        usersService.login(data, (error, results) => {
            if (error) {
                console.error(error)
                res.status(error.statusCode).send({
                    msg_head: "error",
                    msg_body: "Internal Server Error",
                    data: error
                })
            } else if (results.status) { //if status = true
                console.log(results)
                res
                    .status(results.statusCode)
                    .cookie("accessToken", results.accessToken, {
                        httpOnly: true,
                        path: '/',
                        sameSite: 'none',
                        domain: 'fckid.test'
                    })
                    .send({
                        msg_head: "success",
                        msg_body: results
                    })
    
            } else {
                console.error(results)
                res.status(results.statusCode).send({
                    msg_head: "error",
                    msg_body: results
                })
            }
        })
    }
```

this is how my laravel client-side looks like

1. route (im using web.php route)

`Route::post('/auth-login', [LoginController::class, 'login'])->name('auth-login');`

2. LoginController

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $body = $request->post();
        $response = Http::post('http://localhost:3000/users/login', $body);

        if ($response->status() == 200) {
            return redirect()->route('view_student');
            // return $response;
        } else {
            return redirect()->route('login.page');
        }
    }
}
```

what i already tried are

1. give exception to this route to VerifyCsrfToken.php
2. making request from Microsoft Edge, Firefox and Chrome

but those attempts still give me the same result where httponly cookie is not set to the browser.
I try to `$request->getHeaders()` and it igives me correct response where i taught that the server already send correct information as expected.

[image]

on browser it looks like laravel overide the results from server
[image]

it's been 2 days looking for some information that can help me to solve this problem on youtube, google, but no one really talk about this. hope you guys could help me out of this stuck.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Cannot send "httponly" value as false by **PHP** after *new browser updates*.
If you need to use your **cookie** on the *JS side*, set your cookie on the client side with **document.cookie**.

> document.cookie = "test1=Hello; SameSite=None; Secure";